# Multiple fs.writeFile on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, writefile

Straight to the point, I am running an http server in Node.js managing a hotel's check-in/out info where I write all the JSON data from memory to the same file using "fs.writeFile".
The data usually don't exceed 145kB max, however since I need to write them everytime that I get an update from my DataBase, I have data loss/bad JSON format when calls to fs.writeFile happen one  after each other immediately.

Currently I have solved this problem using "fs.writeFileSync" however I would like to hear for a more sophisticated solution and not using the easy/bad solution of sync function.
Using fs.promises results in the same error since again I have to make multiple calls to fs.promises.
According to Node's documentation , calling fs.writefile or fs.promises multiple times is not safe and they suggest using a filestream, however this is not currently an option.

To summarize, I need to wait for fs.writeFile to end normally before attempting any repeated write action, and using the callback is not useful since I don't know a priori when a write action needs to be done.
Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean you are overwriting or truncating the file while the last write request is still being written. If I were you, I would use the [promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_writefile_file_data_options) and heed the warning from the documentation:

`It is unsafe to use fsPromises.writeFile() multiple times on the same file without waiting for the promise to be settled.`

You can `await` the result in a traditional loop, or very carefully use `.then()` to "synchronize" your callbacks, but if you're not doing anything else in your event loop except reading from your database and writing to this file, you might as well just use `writeFileSync` to keep things simple/safe. The asynchronous APIs (callback and Promises) are intended to allow your program to do other things in the meantime; if this is not necessary and the async APIs add troublesome complexity for your code, just use the synchronous APIs. That's true for any node API or library function, not just `fs.writeFile`.

There are also libraries that will perform atomic filesystem operations for you and abstract away the implementation details, but I think these are probably overkill for you unless you describe your use case in more detail. For example, why you're dumping a database to disk as JSON as fast/frequently as you can, rather than keeping things in memory or using event-based incremental updates (e.g. a real, local database with atomicity and consistency guarantees).

Comment: Hello bburhans, thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your response!
Since my app is mainly an http server,yes I do other things rather than simply input/output, although with not a great amount of requests. I will review again the promises solution but the first time I had no luck.

To explain more I have a:`function updateRoom(data){ ...update things in memory... writetoDisk(); }`
and the function writetoDisk(){
fsWriteFile(....)
}

Making the function writetoDisk an async function and implementing "await" inside it still does not solve the problem since the updateRoom function will call the writetoDisk without waiting for it to end.
The ".then" approach can not be implemented since my updateRoom is being called constantly and dynamically .

If you happen to know 1-2 thing about async-await you are more than welcome to explain me a bit more, thanks again nevertheless!

Comment: Correct: making `writeToDisk()` an `async function` will require `await`ing its result, or similar, and that's intended. Promises tend to propagate in `async`/`await` code; if something depends on a `Promise`, you may not be able to proceed synchronously until it has been resolved or rejected (either way, _fulfilled_). Without seeing the rest of your code, I cannot say why `updateRoom` should or should not also be `async`, but consider that as an option; it may be a decent solution.

Comment: You also implied you're "thrashing" the disk on every request, rather than frequently updating objects in memory and then periodically flushing the memory to disk (e.g. with a `setInterval` timer that dumps your JSON). Why are you writing the JSON to disk, and why so frequently? Is it absolutely necessary, or can it be done another way, e.g. a proper database or just an eventually-consistent disk cache?